# Convert links to another domain

Tags: .htaccess

I want convert links to another domain

**From this** : `www.old.net/upload/namefolder/namefile.mp3`

**To** : `www.new.net/upload/namefolder/namefile.mp3`

using `.htaccess`

How can I do this?

Comment: A general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this hope it will work fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:mp3)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.net [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.net/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.net [R=301,L]
```